# Is $P(x,y)$ different from $P((x,y))$?

Tags: notation, predicate-logic

The symbols $P(x,y)$ and $P(z)$ indicate generally the concept of "predicate", but if $(a,b)$ is (ordered) 2-tuple, and in $P(z)$ I have $z=(a,b)$, Is $P(a,b)$ different from $P((a,b))$? .. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The notation $P(a,b)$ is short for $P((a,b))$. The same happens with functions. It's common to abbreviate $f((x,y))$ by $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @GitGud, oh.. thanks soo much! :)

Comment: No problem.${}$

Comment: you was extremely supportive! :)

Comment: @GitGud, if I have $Z:=\{(x,y)|x \in A \wedge y \in B\}$, is it $Z:=\{z|z=(x,y) \wedge P(z):=x \in A \wedge y \in B\}$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be $Z=\{z\mid \exists x\in A\exists y\in B(z=(x,y))\}$.

Comment: you're right, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @GitGud, therefore also $A \cup B=\{x | x \in A \vee x \in B\}$ should be $A \cup B= \{x| \exists y \in A(y=x) \vee \exists z \in B(z=x)\}$.. or not?

Comment: That's one way to write it, yes.