# What is $P(x,y)$ means in probability

Tags: probability

I'm try to understand what's conditional entropy while I already know what's entropy.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy

Wiki used $P(x,y)$ to proof the forum of conditional entropy.

I understand Bayes' theorem, but I don't know what $P(x,y)$ is.

In previous question [Is $P(x,y)$ different from $P((x,y))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816396/is-px-y-different-from-px-y) The author said it's "predicate". What is that means ?

Is $P(x,y) = P(x|y)*P(y) = P(y,x)$ ?

This notation can't be found in Wiki's "Conditional probability" page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability

I didn't ask this question without doing any effort. In fact, it has took me an hour to find the answer.

Could anyone tell me what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(x,y)$ means the probability of $x$ **and** $y$ both occuring.

Comment: It's simpler than I thought. Thank you